# Bash: Return the most recently edited file in a specified directory

Tags: terminal, bash

For a bash script I am currently developing I want to access the name of the most recently edited file (including folders but not subdirectories) in a specified directory. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @fedorqui suggested You can do:

`ls -1t | awk '{ print $9; exit}'`

**Old post:**

You can get it using `awk` and `tail`

`ls -lrt /path/to/folder/ | tail -1 | awk '{ print $9 }'`

Comment: Note you can improve it by using `ls -lt` (without `-r` that reverses) and then skip `tail -1` by doing `awk '{print $9; exit}'`

Comment: `ls -lt` gives "total XXXX" on the first line.

Comment: As per the `-l` part. You can use `1` (one) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -t /path/to/folder/ | sed -n 1p
```

<sup>`-t` sorts ls by date modified. The output is piped to sed to get the first line of the output.</sup>

Comment: Don't You print only the third file in first column by using this `sed` command?

Comment: @Mateusz ls, when piped, doesn't print in columns. I've made the answer much simpler though, printing the first line since if you haven't aliased ls to show hidden files etc then the first line is all that's necessary since there's no total/etc.

Comment: You can also do `ls -t /path/to/folder/ | head -1` which I think is slightly more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing `ls` is helpful in most of the cases, but [sometimes it is not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

To have a 100% sure solution, you can use the `find` command and make it print the last time all files were accessed. By printing it in a numeric way, they you can sort the list and print the last one.

```
find /your/path -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%Y %n" | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

#### Explanation

- `-maxdepth 1` does not go deeper in the directory structure.
- `xargs -0 stat -c "%Y %n"` gets the file name and prints its time of last modification plus the name of the file. (from `man stat`: "%Y     time of last modification, seconds since Epoch")
- `sort -n` orders the list numerically, being the first the oldest.
- `tail -1` gets the last of the list.
- `cut -d' ' -f2-` removes the printing of the datetime.

Comment: There's no `-printf` operator on OS X `find.`  

`find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: Oh, thanks @MateuszSzlosek Just updated with an approach with `print0` and then `xargs`. I am curious to see if it works. It should...

Comment: `stat: illegal option -- c`

Comment: Let's try with `stat -f` as described in [Last modified date of a directory in OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197938/last-modified-date-of-a-directory-in-osx)

Comment: `-print0` option gives me concatenated output of `ls`